# GridView renders items with a tiny gap between them

Tags: flutter

I need a grid of identical widgets in my app. The widgets are square and there must be no gap between them. I can't get this working, as there are always seemingly random gaps between some of the widgets. Sometimes there are a lot of gaps, sometimes just between a few of them, depending on the size of the app window.

Here's the smallest example I could come up with that displays the problem:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const TestApp());

class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const Test(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 7,
        children: List.generate(49, (index) {
        return Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black,
          ));
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If I run this in one of the embedded DartPads on flutter.dev, this is what I get:
[image: Gaps between all widgets]

Moving the separator between code and rendering window, I might get this instead:
[image: Gaps between some of the widgets]

Because the GridView defaults to 0.0 padding between widgets, I would have expected a huge, perfectly black square to be the result. Where do the gray borders between (some of) the widgets come from, and how do I get rid of them?

Comment: Did you try various clipBehavior settings for the Container... I seem to recall this being related to that in another posting, but I can't remember what the resolution (heh) was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening when, in this case, the width given to the GridView is not a multiple of the number of columns.  There are a few pixels left over, and these are the gaps you see.

If you restrict to a multiple of the number of columns then the gaps disappear.  e.g.

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({super.key});

  final numColumns = 7;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: SizedBox(
        width: _width(context),
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: numColumns,
          children: List.generate(numColumns * numColumns, (index) {
            return Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  double _width(BuildContext context) {
    final w = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width;

    return (w ~/ numColumns) * numColumns.toDouble();
  }
```

Comment: What? I just ran your code, the white lines are still there.

Comment: That's weird, doing that made them disappear for me.  I ran it on Windows, and they didn't show no matter how I resized the window.  (You will see white borders on the right and bottom with the code as it is.)

Comment: Just tested, and it works on web, mobile and desktop.  But not on dartpad.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but it did point me in the right direction. Calculating the largest possible widget size that is a multiple of the physical pixel size of the current device, and then setting the SizedBox size to numColumns*widgetSize, the aliasing artefacts are gone. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Why is this happening?

"You're drawing a series of rectangles adjacent to each other, on top of a different background color, but they don't quite line up with the physical pixel boundaries. This means we try to antialias the edges, and each one is painted on top of the background, so the background shows up in the antialiasing."

What's the solution?

1. "The second is to wrap all those widgets with a `RepaintBoundary`, which will cause them to all be painted as one graphic which is then anti-aliased once with the parent. That might not solve the issue, depending on exactly what the alignment ends up being, but it should be better."
2. "In general though the right answer is the first suggestion here; don't put two adjacent boxes with the same background color, just put the background color on the common background."

Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15035#issuecomment-370028740

Using suggestion **2.**, the reproducible example you provided is fixed:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Changes (see comments):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: ColoredBox(
      /// provide a background color which is the same color as the GridView's
      /// cells background color.
      color: Colors.black,
      child: GridView.count(
        ...
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't work for me though because the actual widgets are different colors so I can't use the background to work around the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem. See:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15035
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17084
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25009

As a workaround I came up with, you can set a `Border` with a `width` of `0` to the `BoxDecoration`:

```
 Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black,
              border: Border.all(width: 0), // <-- Set this
            ),
          );
```

---

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const TestApp());

class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const Test(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 7,
        children: List.generate(49, (index) {
          return Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black, border: Border.all(width: 0)),
            child: Text(
              'hi',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That seems to work for the minimal example, but it didn't work with the slightly more complex widgets I'm actually using. Thanks for the tip though!